# How to save info such as a user name to the device?

Tags: flutter

I'd like to provide a "Remember Me" for my flutter app's login screen. Can someone point me in the right direction of how I can read and write some info to the device such as the user name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of SharedPreferences you can store the info locally use the dependencies in pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.7+3
```

and import the package :

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';



String userName;
String userId;
String salary;



_saveValues(bool val, int screen) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString("name", responseJson.name);
    prefs.setString("id", "userId");
    prefs.setString("salary", "1200000");

}

getSharedPreferencesValue() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    userName  = prefs.getString("name")?? "";
    userId  = prefs.getString("password")?? "";
    salary  = prefs.getString("salary")?? "";
}
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: Thanks Sanjeev. This got me started. I can get the remember me checkbox to remember it's state, but I'm having trouble with the user name field. I've created a new question for that. But thanks very much for this code. Have a great day.

Comment: Yeah i reviewed it and will give you the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into shared preferences?
https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences